# Fullcalendar theming

Tags: css, node.js, fullcalendar, meteor-blaze

My Code

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import allLocales from '@fullcalendar/core/locales-all';
import bootstrapPlugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap';
import '@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/list/main.css';
import '@fullcalendar/bootstrap/main.css';

calendar = new Calendar(calendarDom, {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin, bootstrapPlugin ],
    id: 'calendar-view',
    height,
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    contentWidth: 'auto',
    defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
    editable: true,
    eventStartEditable: true,
    eventResizableFromStart: true,
    eventDurationEditable: true,
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap4', // nothing is applied
    timezone: 'local',
    selectable: true,
    header: {
      left: 'title, today, prev, next',
      center: 'listDay, listWeek, listMonth, addEvent',
      right: 'dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek, timeGridDay',
    },
    buttonText: {
      ...
    },
    navLinks: true,
    nowIndicator: true,
    businessHours: {
      ...
    },
    locales: allLocales,
    locale: TAPi18n.getLanguage(),
```

According to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrap-theme, I should be able to use different themes like bootstrap4 by setting `themeSystem: 'bootstrap4'` i.e.

But somehow all i get is the default theme.

What am i missing?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong version of the docs. That version you linked to is for fullCalendar version 3. But your code is version 4. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/theming - what you need to do is very slightly different

Comment: thanks, i posted a wrong link, in v4 (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrap-theme) i have the same problem

Comment: Ok but did you notice in that version you should be specifying the them as "bootstrap" not "bootstrap4"

Comment: Yes, i already tried. Also i tried using `standard` as parameter. what i may be missing are the two hrefs to bootstrap and fontawesome. I am not sure how to include these with a blae / jade template system

Comment: I don't know anything about those template systems, sorry. But I can see how you included the fullCalendar CSS files. I would guess you should follow a similar process to include another file, assuming it exists in your project.